# XSD extend a complex type

Tags: xsd

I'm trying to extend an existing complextype in a XSD file.

I have created a new xsd file and included it at the end of all the master XSD files includes.

The problem I'm having is that it seems to add my extension but it removes the existing elements other than those defined in asset_abstract

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Code I don't want to modify

```
<xs:complexType name="Feature_Cadastre_Lot" abstract="false">
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>Represents the boundary of a titled, or proposed lot</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:complexContent>
  <xs:extension base="asset_abstract">
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:element name="LotNo" type="String_32" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The lot number as described on the originating survey plan</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="PlanNo" type="String_32" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The plan number of the originating survey plan.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="CancelledLotPlan" type="String_32" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The lot on plan cancelled by this boundary if applicable.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="TitledArea_sqm" type="Float_Positive_NonZero" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The area in square metres enclosed by the boundary, as described by the survey plan.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Geometry" type="geometry_area_multipatch_simple" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>The geometry of this feature in coordinate space.  May contain holes and islands. Boundaries must consist of straight lines.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
```

Code I can import to extend the scheme.

```
  <xs:complexType name="Feature_Cadastre_Lot">
<xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="asset_abstract">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="LMS_ID_1" type="String_32" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>The Land Management System ID as defined by the LMS Team</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LMS_ID_2" type="String_32" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>The Land Management System ID as defined by the LMS Team</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
```

OK I've created a bare bones exmaple and I still can't get it to work now using visual studio as I wanna make sure its not the tool :) , I still can't get it too work as yours is :( I must be missing something.

Basically I've added 2 files Master.xsd and local.xsd
Master wraps the remote project I can't / don't want to modify direct and local.xsd is where all our site specific stuff (redefining as it is called).

Master.xsd

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="project.xsd">
  </xs:include>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="local.xsd">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>A File I can add my overwrites to</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:include>
  </xs:schema>
```

project.xsd

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="remote.xsd">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>A File that contains the complexType I want to add elments to. But not modify otherwise</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:include>
  <xs:element name="Master_Project">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>The Project.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ProjectData">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ExistingElement" type="ExistingElementType">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>An Existing Element That I would Like To Add To.</xs:documentation>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

local.xsd

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:redefine schemaLocation="./remote.xsd">
   <xs:complexType name="ExistingElementType">
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="ExistingElementType">
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="newTest"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>
```

remote.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:complexType name="ExistingElementType">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="someProperty"/>
      <xs:element name="someSecondProperty"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And where I do all the redefining eventually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to keep the name of the complex type as "Feature_Cadastre_Lot" **and** extend it with additional content, then you are looking at **redefine** instead. The net effect is that all references to "Feature_Cadastre_Lot", preexisting and new, will include the newly added content.

If you want this in some, but not all of the existing content, there is no solution to it (redefine is all or nothing).

The redefine has the following layout:

```
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="must resolve to your XSD">
  <xs:complexType name="Feature_Cadastre_Lot">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Feature_Cadastre_Lot">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="LMS_ID_1" type="String_32" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>The Land Management System ID as defined by the LMS Team</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LMS_ID_2" type="String_32" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>The Land Management System ID as defined by the LMS Team</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:redefine>
```

The result will look like this:

[image: Redefined type]

You can see the highlighted sequence as showing the added content.

In Visual Studio 2010, the content also shows ok:

[image: VS2010 redefine]

Notice the second sequence at the bottom.

Comment: redefine seems to be the direction I need to go. however it doesn't seem to take effect, it doesn't overwrite the existing Feature_Cadastre_Lot type I'm missing something simple ...

Comment: @Jamo, can you please be more specific as to how are you using it? For e.g., you're using some editor and you can't see the modified diagram? Or are you using some sort of xsd to code binding tool (in which case maybe redefine is not supported)?

Comment: I've been using XSDDiagram to help read the scheme, but I have also loaded it in visual studio and still not working.

Comment: @Jamo, I've updated the post to show the redefines in QTAssistant and Visual Studio 2010; as far as I am concerned, the results show as expected; if you're not getting the same with your tool, blame that :)....

Comment: thankyou for your time I'm so close I know it something just isn't clicking for me. I've updated my post with some examples that show the project layout and how i think I'm going to modify it for our local site, I am able to open it in Visual Studio I see my redefine, however it still isn't using the redefined type and instead uses the initial one...

Comment: @Jamo, what is the "it" in `**it** still isn't using the redefined type `?

Comment: ok this is odd I open the schema in Visual Studio and edit my redefine type name add a 1 to the end save it the remove the 1 and save it again and it now displays in the content model correctly... however once I close visual studio and open it back up I no longer see the additional properties, and the "it" referes to the content model viewer in visual studio which I would imagine shows the end schema?

Comment: I don't have enough rep on this stack to up vote your answer but it was smack on from word go Petru, the schema verifies with the added lms properties it just doesn't display them visually ...