# xsd-reverse-enginering throws unknown type

Tags: grails, xsd

Was playing around with the xsd-reverse-enginering plugin for grails, and got a bit of a problem which I think I know what it is, but not how to resolve it.

Have a huge xsd file containing a relatively advanced schema, and thought I would try to see if I could save my self a lot of time by getting grails to create a gorm object from it. The problem is that the agency that made the xsd file have named a number of XML types based on what the data is. For example, they have an element called MessageType

```
        <xs:element name="MessageCategory" type="MessageType" id="S1.1">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>The type of message: either an original Submission (NewSubmission), an update on a submission (SubmissionVariation), a complete replacement of one message with another (SubmissionReplacement) or submission that should not have been sent (SubmissionVoid) that should be effectively deleted.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
```

That throws the below error

```
Unknown simpleType: MessageType
```

Any ideas on how I can manage this, could I for example define the types or something?

Comment: Anyone knows a simple way of adding the simple types, could work for me.

Comment: Based on the documentation of the element, can't you have an `enum` for `MessageType` with `NewSubmission`, `SubmissionVariation`, `SubmissionReplacement` and `SubmissionVoid` ?

Comment: I didn't manage to use much in the way of documentation on it, how would those help me?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to declare this type you should define the type tags in a proper way (as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8w07bk3h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

for instance: a simple type definition (like a number)

```
<xs:simpleType name="MessageType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
    <xs:maxInclusive value="100"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

a complex type definition (called an element)

```
<xs:element name="MessageType">

  <xs:simpleType ...>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType ...>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:element>
```

Comment: I can not change the XML, that is part of my issue, I would love for the organisation that writes the XML to follow proper formatting, but they don't. Thats why I need to get the grails module to figure it out.

Comment: can you try to define a new xsd that will inherit it's ptoperties from the 'locked' xsd? something like shown in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084145/xsd-extend-a-complex-type